# MongoDB: Find Subdocument in Array Matching Parameters

Tags: mongodb

In MongoDB I would like to find a document based on the values of a subdocument meeting certain parameters. Specifically I have a document structured like this:

```
{
  name: "test",
  data: [{
    name: "test1",
    start: 0,
    end: 2
  },
  {
    name: "test2",
    start: 15
    end: 18
  }]
}
```

How can I tell MongoDB to only return my document if the start time for a data subdocument is less than 5 and the end time for the same subdocument is greater than 5? Currently, if I do

```
db.foo.findOne({
  'data.start': { $lte: 5 },
  'data.end': { $gte: 5 }
})
```

it will return my document always because 5 is greater than 0 and less than 18. How can I tell MongoDB to only return my document if 5 (or whatever value) is greater than 0 and less than 2 OR greater than 15 and less than 18?

Answer (score 79, accepted):

You want to use [$elemMatch](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/elemMatch/#op._S_elemMatch).

```
db.foo.findOne({ data: { $elemMatch : {
  start: { $lte: 5 },
  end: { $gte: 5 }
  }}
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Came across this post thinking of cheating the code which wasn't there ;) So thought of sharing the code snippet in `Java` using [spring-data-mongodb](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.data/spring-data-mongodb-parent/1.8.1.RELEASE)

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo("localhost", 27017);
MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongo, "db");
Query query = new Query();
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("data").elemMatch(
         Criteria.where("start").lte(5)
        .andOperator(Criteria.where("end").gte(5))));
Foo foo = mongoTemplate.findOne(query, Foo.class);
```

Comment: can you give a code snippet like that using morphia?