# Query to find a subdocument in MongoDB

Tags: java, database, mongodb, mongodb-query, bson

Alright, i've got a simple question. I have a simple Document in MongoDB which holds a sub-document called "penalties".
Now i want to find the Document (here with the _id "Cammeritz") by a String in the sub-document ("penalties"), e.g. "penaltyid = 0f77d885-6597-3f47-afb1-0cee2ea3ece1". Can you maybe help me? Best would be an explanation for Java but it is okay if you maybe just help with a normal MongoDB query.

```
{
    "_id" : "Cammeritz",
    "penalties" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "date" : ISODate("2017-09-25T20:01:23.582Z"),
            "penaltyid" : "0f77d885-6597-3f47-afb1-0cee2ea3ece1",
            "reason" : "Hacking",
            "teammember" : "Luis",
            "type" : "ban"
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : null,
            "date" : ISODate("2017-09-25T20:01:23.594Z"),
            "penaltyid" : "7f5411b0-e66a-33b3-ac4f-4f3159aa88a9",
            "reason" : "Spam",
            "teammember" : "BluingFX",
            "type" : "kick"
        }
    ],
    "isBanned" : true,
    "isMuted" : false
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MongoDB: Find Subdocument in Array Matching Parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11823296/mongodb-find-subdocument-in-array-matching-parameters)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oops, I misread your question. You'll need to use dot notation. `db.collection.find( { penalties.penaltyid: '0f77d885-6597-3f47-afb1-0cee2ea3ece1' } )` For more info see [Query on a Nested Field](http://Oops,%20I%20misread%20your%20question.%20You'll%20need%20to%20use%20dot%20notation.%20%60db.collection.find(%20%7B%20penalties.penaltyid:%20'0f77d885-6597-3f47-afb1-0cee2ea3ece1'%20%7D%20)).

---

Original answer:

`db.collection.find( { penalties: "0f77d885-6597-3f47-afb1-0cee2ea3ece1" } )` should work. For more see [Query an Array for an Element](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/query-arrays/#query-an-array-for-an-element) from the mongodb docs. I'm not very familiar with Java so I can't help much there.

Comment: Basically my MongoDB GUI (Robo) gives me an Error: "Error: Line 1: Unexpected token ."

Comment: edit: I think it was a problem with my client, in Java it works perfectly, so for everyone who needs the answer, here it is: Document d = getCollection().find(eq("penalties.penaltyid", s)).first();