# find sub array documents in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm working with following document

```
{
"_id" : 123344223,
"firstName" : "gopal",
"gopal" : [ 
{
 "uuid" : "123",
 "name" : "sugun",


"kiran" : [ 
{
 "uuid" : "456",
 "name" : "ghb"
}

       ]
}
]
}
```

I want to retrieve name from the first document of array kiran and print it in a table...

here is what i have tried

```
Template.table.helpers({
ProductManager: function () {
return ProductManager.find({_id:123344223},{gopal:{$elemMatch:{uuid:"123"}}});
}
 })
```

where ProductManager is my collection and defined in common.js

```
ProductManager = new Meteor.Collection("ProductManager");
```

Here is my template

```
<template name="table">
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>NAME</th>
<th>UUID</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{{#each ProductManager.gopal.kiran}}
<tr>
 <td>{{name}}</td>
 <td>{{uuid}}</td>
 </tr>
 {{/each}}
 </tbody>
 </table>
```

when i tried this

```
ProductManager.find({_id:123344223},{gopal:{$elemMatch:{uuid:"123"}}});
```

Iam able get this in mongo shell

```
{
"_id" : 123344223,
"firstName" : "gopal",
"gopal" : [ 
{
 "uuid" : "123",
 "name" : "sugun",


"kiran" : [ 
{
 "uuid" : "456",
 "name" : "ghb"
}

       ]
}
]
}
```

but cant print name and uuid of Kiran array in the table....... plzz help me to solve this problem... Thanks in advance

Comment: Please correct your document structure. Currently it is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check your json format as it doesn't look valid to me
2. Check if autopublish / insecure is missing from your meteor project, if yes implement pub/sub functionality

Discovermeteor has a good guide for that
[Discovermeteor](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/understanding-meteor-publications-and-subscriptions/)

Another stackoverflow post for sub-document searches
[How to write Mongo query to find sub document with condition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15081463/how-to-write-mongo-query-to-find-sub-document-with-condition)