# Finding sub elements in a array in meteor

Tags: mongodb, meteor

I'm working with following document

```
{
"_id" : 123344223,
"firstName" : "gopal",
"gopal" : [ 
    {
        "uuid" : "123",
        "name" : "sugun",
        "sudeep" : [ 
            {
                "uuid" : "add32",
                "name" : "ssss"
            }, 
            {
                "uuid" : "fdg456",
                "name" : "gfg"
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        "uuid" : "222",
        "name" : "kiran"
    }
]
}
```

I want to retrieve name from the first document of array sudeep and print it in a table...

here is what i have tried

```
Template.table.helpers({
ProductManager: function () {
return ProductManager.findOne({_id:123344223},{gopal:{$elemMatch:{uuid:"123"}}});
}
 })
```

where ProductManager is my collection and defined in common.js

```
ProductManager = new Meteor.Collection("ProductManager");
```

Here is my template

```
<template name="table">
<table>
<thead>
<tr>
<th>NAME</th>
<th>UUID</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
{{#each ProductManager.gopal.sudeep}}
<tr>
<td>{{name}}</td>
<td>{{uuid}}</td>
</tr>
{{/each}}
</tbody>
</table>
```

when i tried this

```
ProductManager.findOne({_id:123344223},{gopal:{$elemMatch:{uuid:"123"}}});
```

Iam able get this in mongo shell

```
{
    "_id" : 123344223,
    "gopal" : [ 
        {
            "uuid" : "123",
            "name" : "sugun",
            "sudeep" : [ 
                {
                    "uuid" : "add32",
                    "name" : "ssss"
                }, 
                {
                    "uuid" : "fdg456",
                    "name" : "gfg"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

but cant print name and uuid of "sudeep" in the table....... plzz help me to solve this problem... Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a duplicate I guess, pls see my answer on the other question here: [Check autopublish](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28361458/4491806)

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
{{#each ProductManager}}
  {{#with this.gopal.sudeep}}
      ...
  {{/with}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: hey thanks for your reply......but its not working.....can you please suggest me some other way to solve this

Answer (score 0):

If you know the id of the document you can write this query

```
ProductManager.find({_id: productID}, {"gopal.sudeep":1});
```

This query return a cursor with all data **only** at gopal.sudeep and then you can iterate through this cursor at you template to display name and uuid of all elements

So at js file you can write

```
Template.table.helpers({
     ProductManager: function () {
       return ProductManager.find({_id: youid}, {"gopal.sudeep":1});
     }
});
```

And at your template file

```
<tbody>
  {{#each ProductManager}}
    <tr>
      <td>{{name}}</td>
      <td>{{uuid}}</td>
    </tr>
  {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

Good luck!

Comment: hey thanks for your reply......but its not working.....can you please suggest me some other way to solve this

Comment: The query ProductManager.find({_id: youid}, {"gopal.sudeep":1}); what did return

Comment: {
    "_id" : 123,
    "gopal" : [ 
        {
            "sudeep" : [ 
                {
                    "uuid" : "add32",
                    "name" : "ssss"
                }, 
                {
                    "uuid" : "fdg456",
                    "name" : "gfg"
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {}
    ]
}

Comment: I want my output to be like this{ "_id" : 456, "gopal" : [ {  "uuid" : "123",
            "name" : "sugun","sudeep" : [ { "uuid" : "add32", "name" : "ssss" }] }] }

Comment: Try this to see if it works ProductManager.findOne({_id: youid})["gopal"]["sudeep"][0]. Print out the correct results?

Comment: db.People.aggregate([
    {$match: {_id: 123}}, 
    {$unwind: "$gopal"}, 
    {$unwind: "$gopal.sudeep"}, 
    {$match: {"gopal.uuid": "123", "gopal.sudeep.uuid" : "add32"}}
 ])   I tried this and succeded....Thanks for your response