# Mongodb: Get Documents where ALL embedded Documents satisfy query

Tags: mongodb

I have the following query:

```
db.MyData.find( { "SubItems.EndDate" : { $lte : new Date() } })
```

Which returns me any document in my data where one of its embedded SubItems EndDate is in the past, but how do I alter this to return me the document only if **all** of its SubItems satisfy the query

In the below example my original query would return both documents but I only want it to return the second one.

```
{
    "_id" : 1,
    "name" : "item1"
    "SubItems" : [
        {
            "EndDate": ISODate("2016-10-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        },
        {
            "EndDate": ISODate("2016-04-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        },
    ]
}
{
    "_id" : 2,
    "name" : "item2"
    "SubItems" : [
        {
            "EndDate": ISODate("2016-02-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        },
        {
            "EndDate": ISODate("2016-03-01T00:00:00.000Z"),
        },
    ]
}
```

Comment: Can you show us some sample documents and your expected output?

Comment: refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10885044/mongodb-how-to-query-for-a-nested-item-inside-a-collection it might help to you

Answer (score 1):

After seeing this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10489649/mongodb-find-a-document-with-all-subdocuments-satisfying-a-condition?rq=1)

I managed to achieve what i needed with the following query:

```
edb.Bookings.find( { "ItineraryItems.EndDate" : { $not : {  $gt : new Date() } } })
```